# CORBA::Short value checking

Tags: c++, corba, short

I have an API I have declared a CORBA Short as method input parameter.

```
char* WirelessServ::allocateNewService(
        const char*  csproductlineName,
        CORBA::Long  clAccountNo,
        CORBA::Short cshServiceNoCategoryFlag,
    ) IT_THROW_DECL((
        CORBA::SystemException, 
        ArtixToOrbix::GenericException
    ))
```

Now I want to check whether the input value that comes in the 'cshServiceNoCategoryFlag' parameter is actually NULL OR does it contain 0 (numeric zero).

But it seems that NULL short value is also treated 0 (zero). Please advise.

Comment: It's unclear what you asked because NULL is defined as 0 (`# define NULL ((void*) 0)`) , then it is the same value.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment your CORBA implementation calls into your `allocateNewService` operation each argument does have a valid value, for a `CORBA::Short` this is a numeric value, for example `0`, it can't be `NULL`.

Looks you are using an ancient CORBA implementation, implementations supporting the IDL to C++11 language mapping use a `int16_t` as argument type for a `short` and `std::string` for a `string`.